# mysqli execute returns empty boole

Tags: php, database, mysqli, boolean

I have noted the warning that posts exist with similar titles, but they do not demonstrate the issue I am having. They refer to ajax and timeout issues which I don't think I have.

The php function below is called to insert details from a web form into the mysql database. This functions returns a value but unfortunately it always returns "Error, -4". This means that:

1. The prepare statement was prepared successfully
2. the parameters were bound successfully

but:

3. the execute() boole returned was not 1.
4. No new row is inserted into the mysql database

I introduced a lot of the log calls to try and solve the issue myself but I have hit the limit of my understanding of mysql.

As you can see I have also included a connection test to the mysql db. Everything, (php,mysql and firefox) run on the same physical host.

```
function submit_new_prod_code_request($BULK_LIQUID_CODE,$PROD_DESC,
                                  $SKU_TYPE,$SKU_PROD_NAME,
                                  $SKU_PROD_DESC,
                                  $SUBUNIT_VOL,$SUBUNITS,$LITRE_PER_UNIT,
                                  $PERC_ALC,$CN_CODE,$ERN_CODE,
                                  $ERN_CODE_DOMESTIC,
                                  $VAT_APP, $VAT_RATE,
                                  $DUTY_RATE,$DUTY_PER_UNIT,
                                  $TENANT,
                                  $PH_MIN,$PH_MAX,
                                  $ACID_MIN,$ACID_MAX,
                                  $COLOUR_MIN,$COLOUR_MAX,
                                  $TURBIDITY,
                                  $EAN_BOTTLE,$EAN_PALLET,$PALLET_TYPE,
                                  $LAYERS_PER_PALLET,$CASES_PER_LAYER,
                                  $BOTTLE_TYPE,$BOTTLE_CLOSURE,
                                  $CASE_CODE,$DIVISION,
                                  $BRIX_MIN,$BRIX_MAX,
                                  $GIFT,
                                  $db,$log,$session){

$submit_success = -1;

if ($db->connect_error) {
    $log->lwrite($session['first_name'].' '.$session['last_name'].' Prod Tree db connection test: '.$db->connect_error);

}
else{
    $log->lwrite($session['first_name'].' '.$session['last_name'].' Prod Tree db connection test: connected');

}
$log->lwrite($session['first_name'].' '.$session['last_name'].' Prod Tree connection status:'.$db->stat());

//submit new prod code to product tree
$sql_str=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO product_tree (BULK_LIQUID, DESCRIPTION, SKU_TYPE, SKU_PROD_NAME, SKU_PROD_DESC, SUBUNIT_VOL, SUBUNIT, LITRES_PER_UNIT, PERC_ALC, CN_CODE, ERN_CODE, ERN_CODE_DOMESTIC, VAT_APPLICABLE, VAT_RATE, DUTY_RATE, DUTY_PER_UNIT, tenant_name, ph_min, ph_max, acid_min, acid_max, colour_min, colour_max, turbidity, ean_bottle, ean_pallet, pallet_type, layers_per_pallet, cases_per_layer, bottle_type, closure, case_code, division, perc_brix_min, perc_brix_max, GIFT_PACK) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

if(!$sql_str){
    $log->lwrite($session['first_name'].' '.$session['last_name'].' Prod Code Create Error 1: '.$db->error);
    $log->lwrite($session['first_name'].' '.$session['last_name'].' Prod Code Create Error 1: '.$sql_str->error);
    $ret=array('Error:',-1);
}
else{
    $rs=$sql_str->bind_param('sssssddddssssdddsdddddddsssddssssdds',$bulk_liquid_code,$PROD_DESC,$SKU_TYPE,$SKU_PROD_NAME,$SKU_PROD_DESC,$subunit_vol,$subunits,$litre_per_unit,$perc_alc,$CN_CODE,$ERN_CODE,$ERN_CODE_DOMESTIC,$VAT_APP, $VAT_RATE, $DUTY_RATE,$DUTY_PER_UNIT,$tenant,
                             $PH_MIN,$PH_MAX,
                             $ACID_MIN,$ACID_MAX,
                             $COLOUR_MIN,$COLOUR_MAX,
                             $TURBIDITY,
                             $EAN_BOTTLE,$EAN_PALLET,$PALLET_TYPE,
                             $LAYERS_PER_PALLET,$CASES_PER_LAYER,
                             $BOTTLE_TYPE,$BOTTLE_CLOSURE,
                             $CASE_CODE,$DIVISION,
                             $BRIX_MIN,$BRIX_MAX,
                             $GIFT);
    if(!$rs){
        $log->lwrite($session['first_name'].' '.$session['last_name'].' Prod Code Create Error 2: '.$sql_str->error);
        $log->lwrite($session['first_name'].' '.$session['last_name'].' Prod Code Create Error 2: '.$db->error);
        $ret=array('Error:',-2);
    }
    else{
        $didwork=$sql_str->execute();
        $log->lwrite($session['first_name'].' '.$session['last_name'].' Prod Tree Create did it work?: '.gettype($didwork));
        $log->lwrite($session['first_name'].' '.$session['last_name'].' Prod Tree Create did it set?: '.isset($didwork));
        $log->lwrite($session['first_name'].' '.$session['last_name'].' Prod Tree Create did it work?: '.$didwork);
        $log->lwrite($session['first_name'].' '.$session['last_name'].' Prod Tree Create did it work?: '.is_null($didwork));


        if(!$sql_str){
            $log->lwrite($session['first_name'].' '.$session['last_name'].' Prod Tree Create Error 2: '.$sql_str->error);
            $log->lwrite($session['first_name'].' '.$session['last_name'].' Prod Tree Create Error 2: '.$db->error);
            $ret=array('Error:',-3);

        }
        else{
            if($didwork==1){
                $ret=array('Success:',1);
            }
            else{
                $ret=array('Error:',-4);
            }
        }
    }
}
$sql_str->close();
return $ret;
```

}

Here is the end of the log with the part I believe the issues lies:

[31/Aug/2017:10:18:34] (check_for_duplicate_sku) USER SURNAME Prod Tree db connection test: connected
[31/Aug/2017:10:18:34] (check_for_duplicate_sku) USER SURNAME Prod Tree connection status:Uptime: 1162  Threads: 1  Questions: 58  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 52  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 46  Queries per second avg: 0.049
[31/Aug/2017:10:18:34] (check_for_duplicate_sku) USER SURNAME Prod Tree Create did it work?: boolean
[31/Aug/2017:10:18:34] (check_for_duplicate_sku) USER SURNAME Prod Tree Create did it set?: 1
[31/Aug/2017:10:18:34] (check_for_duplicate_sku) USER SURNAME Prod Tree Create did it work?:
[31/Aug/2017:10:18:34] (check_for_duplicate_sku) USER SURNAME Prod Tree Create did it work?:

The second last row of the log file should (as I understand) be 1 or 0 (boolean) and the last row is_null should also be a boolean but both are returned with no value (that I can appear to see). Does anyone have any ideas? Am I missing something obvious? I was suspicious that the connection was dieing or it was some timeout issue which is why I did the connection check and stat. Any ideas and thoughts are welcome.

**EDIT 1:** 
$vardump = var_export($didwork,true);

$log->lwrite($session['first_name'].' '.$session['last_name'].' Prod Tree Create VAR DUMP: '.$vardump);

[31/Aug/2017:11:33:56] (check_for_duplicate_sku) USER SURNAME Prod Tree Create VAR DUMP: false

var_export returned false which I guess is the intended behaviour for a boolean according to: http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php

**EDIT 2:**

```
ob_start();
var_dump($didwork);
$result = ob_get_clean();
$log->lwrite($session['first_name'].' '.$session['last_name'].' Prod Tree Create VAR DUMP: '.$result);
```

[31/Aug/2017:12:15:32] (check_for_duplicate_sku) USER SURNAME Prod Tree Create VAR DUMP: bool(false)

var dump appears to label the type returned as boolean (expected) but does the (false) indicate the value of the boolean is false? or unset?

Comment: i would suggest var_export or var_dump or something alike, and btw, why don't you check the `$didwork` in the `if` after?

Comment: Hi Jakumi, thanks for the reply. Do you mean to check $didwork in the if(!$sql_str)? I'll post an update with var_dump of did work.